# Buttons change style at run time

Tags: vb.net

I have a vb.net Windows Forms application using Visual Studio 2010.  At design time my buttons look like this:

[image]

at run time they seem to revert to a Windows classic style:

[image]

It only happens for this project which I took over from a developer who left.  I want them to look like they do at design time.  I'm stumped.  Any ideas?

Comment: how does the app start (main form or sub main)?

Answer (score 3):

If the app starts from a Sub Main rather than a main form (See **Project -> Properties -> StartUp Object**) it might be missing this:

```
Public Sub Main()

    ' probably missing:
    Application.EnableVisualStyles()

    Application.Run(New Form1)

End Sub
```

When starting from a Main sub, be sure that `EnableVisualStyles()` is invoked very early in the procedure *before* any UI Objects are created.

If it starts from a main form, go to the same Project properties and be sure that **both** `Enable application framework` and `Enable XP Visual Styles` are checked.

---

If it *still* doesnt work, turn on `Show All Files` in Solution Explorer and open `Application.myApp` under **My Project**.  Make sure this setting is true:

```
<EnableVisualStyles>true</EnableVisualStyles>
```

This file/setting should be managed by VS, so if it is not being updated to match the IDE, you might have other issues.

Comment: It starts from a main form.  I checked the properties and it is checked.

Comment: Both the `Enable XP Styles` **and** `enable app framework` have to be checked